# Question about embeddings in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Assume I have an embedding $f:X\longrightarrow Y$, and $Z\subset X$ is some closed subscheme of $X$. How does one show that $f^{-1}(\overline{f(Z)}) = Z$?

One direction is trivial, for $f^{-1}(\overline{f(Z)})$ clearly contains $Z$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless you're asking about the scheme structure, this is just a topological question, where the other direction is clear by the definition of the induced topology. Are you asking about the scheme structure, or is the above enough to resolve your question?

Comment: I agree that the question is topological. I thought that in the category of topological spaces an embedding is simply an injection. I didn't know this actually meant that its topology was the induced topology. For example, I didn't know why $f^{-1}(\overline{f(Z)}\setminus f(Z)) = \emptyset$.

Comment: If you now understand the answer to your question, please consider writing an answer to your own question to help future readers. (If there's something that's still not clear, let me know.)